# Trigger ActionMailer from JSON POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

EDIT: This is the working code that I came to from Thomas' answer, there were other mistakes that needed to be fixed as well.

I'm working with a Rails API server that is set up to create shared links for users. I have it set up so that they pass a number of parameters via `POST` and I want to send the mailers and then save the record. I'm able to save the record, but I can't seem to trigger the mailers.

Here is the create action on the controller

```
def create
  @recipients = (share_params[:shared_with])
  @recipients.each do |recipient|
    ShareMailer
      .share_dealsheet(recipient)
      .deliver_now
    end
  @share = current_user.shares.create!(share_params)
  json_response(@share, :created)
end
```

And the ShareMailer class

```
class ShareMailer < ApplicationMailer

  default from: 'no-reply@dealsheetboard.com'

  def share_dealsheet(recipient)
    @recipient = recipient
    mail(to: @recipient, subject: "Test")
  end
end
```

There is also a boilerplate template saved as `share_dealsheet.rb`

If I `POST` the following in Postman, the record is saved, but no mailer is ever triggered (so I assume since the other mailers I'm using output in the console as they are created).

```
{
    "token": "Sbdvmvt2VnzO0n3_thGSfZc1xkjs",
    "shared_with":{
        "1": "someemail@example.com",
        "2": "anotheremail@example.com"
    },
    "expiry": "30 June 2017"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deliver the mail, see the API for more details http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Sending+mail

```
ShareMailer.share_dealsheet(share_params).deliver_now
```

Comment: So simple, thank you! I realized after this there was a problem with the loop, but that's also fixed in the edit above.